# custom validations for timestamp rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a little problem. Anyone can answer how to right validate this case? Maybe need to convert the timestamp to integer, or in something else?

## model: unworked_day.rb

```
class UnworkedDay < ApplicationRecord
  validate :end_date_after_start_date?

  def end_date_after_start_date?
    if unworked_period_to.to_i < unworked_period_from.to_i
       errors.add :unworked_period_to, "Unworked period to should be greater than the unworked period from"
    end
  end
```

## migration

```
  t.timestamp :unworked_period_from
  t.timestamp :unworked_period_to
```

Answer (score 1):

You  can directly compare two timestamp objects like this,

```
  def end_date_after_start_date?
    if unworked_period_to < unworked_period_from
       errors.add :unworked_period_to, "Unworked period to should be greater than the unworked period from"
    end
  end
```

No need to convert in any other data_type